# How to send mail from a HTML form?

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I made a form and my task is to sending mail to the mail server.I tried with `mailto` HTML attributes.But failed.Then start with php.It was not working also.So I badly need help.

```
<form method="post" action="form-to-email.html">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputName">Your Name (required)</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Your Email (required)</label>
                                        <input type="Email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputTextarea">Your Message</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Message" rows="4" name="message"></textarea>
                                    </div>

                                    <button type="submit" value="Send Email" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>

                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

And this is my php code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])&&isset($_POST['email'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
  $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
    $email_from = 'dbgreen71@heidianderson.com.au';
    $email_subject = "New Form submission";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".    
                            "Here is the message:\n $message".    
$to = "dbgreen71@heidianderson.com.au";
  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
}
?>
```

Someone please help me.I really don't find any way to do this task.

Comment: Any error you are getting?

Comment: Your form's action points to an HTML file. Make it the PHP one.

Comment: This code is working fine. check in spam folder. even if mail is not there too. Then server might be blocking. If this is the case then you need to use SMTP. and change this form-to-email.html to form-to-email.php

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy no way the above code works fine. The action attribute is `.html` and should be pointing to `.php`

Comment: no error.I Just add .html.It should show just a success page.

Comment: @PriomSarkar no way a `.html` file does back-end processing. If the above code is truly what you have, the `.php` file can never be called

Comment: If I make action attribute empty.Will any problem happen with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and tell if you get any error:

```
<?php
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $email_subject = "New Form submission";
    $to = "dbgreen71@heidianderson.com.au";
    $subject = $email_subject;
    $email_from = 'dbgreen71@heidianderson.com.au';
    $header = "From:dbgreen71@heidianderson.com.au \r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

    $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);

    if( $retval == true ) {
    echo "Message sent successfully...";
    }else {
    echo "Message could not be sent...";
    $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
    echo $errorMessage;
    }
?>
```

Also I have added error handling code which will help you in near future if you get any errors related to mail.
Another thing, if you need headers then and then only use it, or else it is of no usage. You can even send emails without headers.

Comment: It's working.Thanks